# "Baldguy" cheat in Descent?

Tags: cheats, descent-1

The code base of DXX-Rebirth (open-source Descent I and II implementation) [contains](https://github.com/dxx-rebirth/dxx-rebirth/blob/master/common/include/pcx.h) this line:

> // Load bitmap for little-known 'baldguy' cheat.

A quick googling didn't reveal anything, and there's nothing with that name in the list of [Descent cheat codes](https://www.ign.com/wikis/pc-cheats/Descent_Cheats). What exactly is this "baldguy" cheat?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but is it maybe a joke?

Comment: I'm running DXX 0.60, and I can't use any cheats. Tried D2X on the same release, and I can use cheats. Interesting, will need some more digging!

Comment: Following the change logs and code, looks like this cheat is activated by `ALT+B` during some sort of debriefing window. I don’t have the game installed, so can’t fully verify that information

Comment: I tried ALT+B in the pre-mission Briefing, but no dice

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Hrm. The event handler is found in the [titles.c](https://github.com/arbruijn/dxx-ar/blob/master/d1/main/titles.c#L1037) files. The [changelog](https://github.com/arbruijn/dxx-ar/blob/master/d1/CHANGELOG.txt#L2170) also says "Add BALDGUY cheat for Mac data". So perhaps it's a MAC specific cheat?